# R : Find Column with highest value

Tags: r

I want to find the MAX value in each column and generate info of which column that generate the highest value (Yelow cell in the pic).

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: What happens when two columns have the same high score?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what about it didn't work? Even if we had your code, we wouldn't be able to run it on a picture of data

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution

```
df <- cbind(df,
            do.call(rbind,
                    apply(df[-1], 1, function(v) data.frame(MAX = max(v),Top_Subject = names(v[which.max(v)])))))
```

such that

```
> df
    Name Math Physics History Chemistry Biology MAX Top_Subject
1   Jack    9       8       7         7       4   9        Math
2   Andy    6       8       6         5       5   8     Physics
3  Peter    7      10       7         6       8  10     Physics
4 Ashley    7       6       5         6       8   8     Biology
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Jack", "Andy", "Peter", "Ashley"), Math = c(9, 
6, 7, 7), Physics = c(8, 8, 10, 6), History = c(7, 6, 7, 5), 
    Chemistry = c(7, 5, 6, 6), Biology = c(4, 5, 8, 8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution (in future please c+p the output of dput(df) function in order to generate the example instead of a picture):

```
df2 <- transform(df, max_scores = apply(df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)], 1, max),
                top_sub_per_stud = names(df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)])[apply(df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)], 1, which.max)])
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Jack", "Andy", "Peter", "Ashley"), Math = c(9, 
6, 7, 7), Physics = c(8, 8, 10, 6), History = c(7, 6, 7, 5), 
    Chemistry = c(7, 5, 6, 6), Biology = c(4, 5, 8, 8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```